# Mono profiler "unmatched leave at stack pos"?

Tags: c#, mono, profiling

Hello recently i have been profiling some mono application. Few weeks ago mono profiler outputted some simple reports. But then we make some major refactoring now during profiler run half of the file is filled with errors like :

**unmatched leave at stack pos: 4 for method unknown method 0xb4b1d580**

sometimes with actually method name when it finds symbols. My question is what does this mean? Can i somehow fix those errors? are profiling results affected?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization? If so, [*turn that off*](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/329124/2429).

Comment: When running with `--debug` do you also get `thread %p has %d items on stack` in the output? Ref: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/30754eef7e3c1a7585c0e8de2a58872d52a1a990/mono/profiler/mprof-report.c#L1834

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey I have optimizaton disabled when building with monodevelop.

Comment: @SushiHangover After run with --debug, no i do not have such messages.